# Basic trouble with PHP - Line shift

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress site and I am not very familiar with PHP.
Somehow I have managed to produce the following empty line below the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/miu4b.jpg

So my question is how I can remove or avoid having this empty space below the image.

Here is the PHP for the page. The cause has to be in here somewhere, I think.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template part for displaying the post meta information
 *
 * @package Editor
 */
?>
<div class="entry-meta">
<!-- Grab and display the featured image -->
<?php if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail()) {?>
<a class="frontfeatured-image" href="<?php the_permalink()?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-image')?>
</a>
<?php }?>

<!--
    <ul class="meta-list">
        <?php if ( has_category() ) { ?>
            <li class="meta-cat"><?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php $posttags = get_the_tags(); if ( $posttags ) { ?>
            <li class="meta-tag"><?php the_tags( '' ); ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) ) : ?>
        <li class="meta-comment">
            <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'editor' ), __( '1 Comment', 'editor' ), __( '% Comments', 'editor' ) ); ?></span>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
-->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.entry-meta {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-style: solid;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .entry-meta {
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.frontfeatured-image {
  display: inherit;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-width: 0px;  
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    filter: grayscale(1);
    -moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.5s ease-in; 
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in; 
    -o-transition:-o-transform 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.5s ease-out; 
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.5s ease-out; 
    -o-transition:-o-transform 0.5s ease-out;
    }
    .frontfeatured-image:hover{
    -moz-transform:scale(1.02); 
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.02);
    -o-transform:scale(1.02);
    color: #000000;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried eliminating the white space between the image tag and the link? I find that sometimes in Wordpress templates I need to ensure <?php ... ?> is right up against the tags to avoid white space being interpreted literally. For instance:
`<?php if (true) {?><a 
href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php 
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail-image')
?></a><?php 
} ?>`.

If I had any idea why that happens, I'd submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
.frontfeatured-image img{
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to give a vote. I also don't know how to "accept" the answer. Sorry. Edit: Just accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you apply the following style on your image?

```
.frontfeatured-image img{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Display: block ? Try it on the link as well... Another thing you could try is to use !important on your margins, in case a parent is messing it up. A link would be helpful though.

Comment: It does not really make a visual difference. At least not from what I can see.